# Fancybox not showing 'Picture Preview' Out of the iframe Border

Tags: iframe

I made an `iframe` on the right side of the main page/parent page and added some pictures, these are working with `Fancybox`.

Pictures are not showing their preview out of the iframe. I need the preview in full screen. Need to help in settings.

```js
<!--FancyBox function code--> 
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.fancybox').fancybox();
  });
   </script>
```

```html
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ntzsportsonline.com/source/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ntzsportsonline.com/source/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ntzsportsonline.com/source/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.ntzsportsonline.com/source/jquery.fancybox.css" media="screen" />
<style> .fancybox-custom .fancybox-skin { box-shadow: 0 0 50px #222; } </style>

<iframe src="http://www.ntzsportsonline.com/advertisements.htm" width="335" height="629" name="Advertisements" border="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" target="_blank">
   Technical Problem</iframe>
```

Comment: An [iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) is used to embed another document within the current page, which is why the fancybox remains within the iframe.  Is this a static site or are you using php, ruby or python?  I could give an example if I new more about your set up.

Comment: Hi, I editing and publishing this site in FrontPage 2003. All pages extensions are (.htm). I saw here many fancybox codings to enlarge the picture's preview but still confuse. Please solve this issue.